# ASP Wizard Control nested in ModalPopupExtender and UpdatePanel issues

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Wizard that i display in a ModalPopupExtender  when a button "New Entry" is clicked. The Wizard itself is nested in

```
<div id=Panel1">
  <UpdatePanel>
     <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:wizard>
       </asp:wizard?
     </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

I have set an event for wizard where if finishButton is clicked in wizard then i hide the ModalPopupExtender.

The problem with this is that since i never "close" the popup , the next time the "New entry" button is clicked the popup simply becomes visible and wizard is displayed with all previous entered data.

I know my problem is because of now closing the popupExtender but i couldn't figure out another way to close the popupExtender from within wizard when the finish button is pressed.

can someone please help? thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after little more researching i found the answer myself:

in finishButton_Clicked event i just added the following and the desired result is archived:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString());
```